# Parametrized job using build pipeline plugin on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, pipeline

I've been using build pipeline plugin with Jenkins (v1.534) for a long time now and recently I've tried to create a pipeline with the same job (using different parameters) twice and it seems not possible. It looks like this:

Job A (param env=dev) -> Job B -> Job A (param env=qa)

Is this possible using build pipeline plugin (v1.4)?

Comment: I would be helpful to see some groovy code (jenkinsfile) that specifies parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the Jenkins FLOW plugin...  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FLOW+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only possible if you have Job B automatically setup to trigger job A again, not manual build step.

Job B will automatically trigger downstream via the parameter trigger job plugin. This works fine if you use the automatic build downstream, but the manual hold feature post build job is not smart enough yet to continue on.

Jenkins also has massive failing in plucking upstream variables into downstream jobs, like if jobs are run out of order on a pipeline.

At my work, I duplicate jobs and chain them Build->Deploy to Dev->Deploy to QA->Deploy....XXX and so forth.

Comment: I've been duplicating jobs either. The approach you suggested works fine when I run the jobs outside the Build Pipeline Plugin view I created. However, when I try to access the view page, it crashes.